# AS400 column subfix

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a script that looks similar to the below. the ".1" and ".2" is what confuses me.

```
select field.1, field.2 from db/"file1" C1,db/"file1" P2 inner join field2.1=field2.2
```

is the equivalent for normal TSQL be,

```
select cl.field, p2.field from db.file1 C1 
inner join db.file1 P2  on cl.field2=p2.field2
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My apologies it is early here so I may not have been clear. is field.1 and field.2 the same as saying that field.1 is from the first file and field.2 is from the second file? so another way of writing it would be to use the alias' of c1.field and p2.field ?

Comment: nope.  and what you've posted is not valid syntax for DB2 for IBM i.  You can have a "FIELD.1" as an actual column name, but it'd have to be a quoted name. `SELECT "FIELD.1" from mylib/mytable`

Comment: Charles, valid or not it works and has been working for quite a few years. I am completely new to DB2 for IBM and trying to convert what the previous person did and convert over to querying from openquery using MSSQL but I have to understand what the heck they did so I can write out the equivalent

Comment: The're referring to the columns by position.  field is alias for table.  field.1 is first column on table with alias field.  It's a bad practice to not specifically use names of columns.

Comment: in this example field is not an alias though, field is the actual name of the field. well in this example that is. the actual field name is more like wopqd but for the example I just used basic names.

Comment: How is this code being run?

Comment: So I figured it out, after hours of going through numerous queries that have been prewriten. the .1 or .2 or .3 etc... is the listed place for each of the joined tables(files) tableA, tableB, tableC can be represented in the order in which they are joined. fieldfortablea.1, fieldfortableb.2, fieldfortablec.3

Comment: the jacked up thing is it looks like some of these queries were written half by one person and half by someone else by the fact that there is different syntax styles in the middle of the query